# Access Date Query Problem for Today's Date

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a set of data that includes a field called ReleaseDate, type of Date/Time, that gets written using NOW() at the time a record is added.

I can open the table and filter for today's date and get a result of 152 records.

I can run this following query, enter today's date at the prompts, and also get a result of 152 records.

```sql
SELECT ProductData.ReleaseDate, ProductData.Shift, ProductData.ExtrusionLine, ProductData.RollDensity
FROM ProductData
WHERE (((ProductData.ReleaseDate) Between [Please Enter Start Date mm/dd/yyyy] & " " & #12/30/1899# And [Please Enter End Date mm/dd/yyyy] & " " & #12/30/1899 23:59:59#));
```

If I run the following query no records are retrieved. I cannot figure out why.

```sql
SELECT ProductData.ReleaseDate, ProductData.Shift, ProductData.ExtrusionLine, ProductData.RollDensity
FROM ProductData
WHERE (((ProductData.ReleaseDate)=Date()));
```

From what I have read Date() as a criteria should return any records with today's date. Prompting for the date is not an option.

Comment: Please format queries (e.g. [Instant SQL](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm)) and show them as code as Gustav did for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Gutav's answer, better use:

```sql
WHERE ProductData.ReleaseDate >= Date() AND ProductData.ReleaseDate < DateAdd("d", 1, Date())
```

as this can use an index on `ProductData.ReleaseDate` (faster). See my answer on [Unable to use today's date as a criteria in a query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/240832/146798)

Comment: So now I know I can pull the time portion from ReleaseDate into a field using TimeValue(). Is there a similar criteria I should use if I want to index ReleaseDate?

Comment: The ultimate goal is to query all the records that were submitted during the current shift. Shifts being 7AM - 3PM, 3PM - 11 PM, and 11 PM - 7 AM. the 3rd shift will be tougher because the query should only pull today's records between 11 PM - 12 AM. After 12 AM the query needs to return today's records and the records from the last hour of yesterday.

Comment: The shift info belongs to question not comment! I can update my answer if needed, but you can get the data by just using `ProductData.ReleaseDate >= Shiftstart(Datetime)  AND ProductData.ReleaseDate < DateAdd("h", 8, Shiftstart(Datetime))` as criteria. Don't store time in seperate field, just extract it in a query if needed.

Comment: I apologize, I wasn't attempting to ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

It's because *ReleaseDate* contains a time part (from Now()). You can strip that:

```
WHERE Fix(ProductData.ReleaseDate) = Date();
```

Comment: You lead me on the right path thanks. SELECT DateValue([ReleaseDate]) AS JustDate, ProductData.Shift, ProductData.ExtrusionLine, ProductData.RollDensity
FROM ProductData
WHERE (((DateValue([ReleaseDate]))=Date()));

Comment: _That did not solve my issue_. Yes it did. Here, DateValue does the same as Fix, only is Fix native to SQL.

Comment: There seems to be a difference between `Fix()`and `DateValue()` as `Fix()` doesn't work on linked tables (from MySQL), but does its job on local tables. And `Fix()` can handle Null values (returns Null), `DateValue()` can't.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher: You may have a point. _Fix_ will always work if the field is linked correctly as DateTime. If the field is linked as Text, _DateValue_ will work as it will cast Text to DateTime. Don't know if that should be the case here, but date/time fields should always be of data type DateTime, no exceptions.

Comment: No field is linked as Date/Time.

Comment: Then Fix can't fail, @ComputerVersteher. But with the late info about shift times, it isn't relevant any longer, as a method as you described must be used.